# Algorithm for updating layout of large directed acyclic graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-visualization

I'm looking for a graph layout algorithm that has the following properties:

1. Supports directed acyclic graphs similar to the graphviz `dot` layouts.  There should be a clear direction of flow (no pointers to naive  force-directed algorithms please)
2. Supports larger graphs well over 1000 nodes
3. Supports marginal updates and removals as new nodes come into and are removed from the graph over time
4. Operates quickly at human interactive speeds

I'm not necessarily looking for existing software packages, but if people want to list them I'm in Python, but happy to link out to C/C++/Fortran.

Comment: The only pure python implementation of the dot layout that I have come across is [grandalf](https://github.com/bdcht/grandalf/). The docs indicate though that marginal updates are only possible at the leaves, otherwise you have to re-compute the layout from scratch, which is expected to take up 1 sec for graphs *under* 1000 nodes.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not explicitly looking for a software library or an implementation.  I'm looking for an algorithm.  I'd be just as happy with a reference to a paper.

Comment: There's a nice survey on line: https://cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/